# Why there is Differences for class_copyPropertyList() for two id vars but with the same Class type

Tags: ios, iphone

```
id appdel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  // <--- i have set this delegate to an instance of MyAppDelegate
unsigned int property_count;  // <--- it will have 0 
objc_property_t * property_list = class_copyPropertyList(appdel, &property_count);
the property_list will be nil;
```

But if I use this:

```
id casualcore_app_delegate = objc_getClass("MyAppDelegate");

unsigned int outCount, i;  // <--- outCount will be the correct property count
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(casualcore_app_delegate, &outCount);

for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++)
{
  objc_property_t property = properties[i];
  fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", property_getName(property), property_getAttributes(property));
}
```

Please tell me, why the same function calls return different results?

Comment: In Obj-C every class is also an object. objc_getClass("MyAppDelegate") returns the class object, not an instance of that class.

Comment: Also, `id` is not a type of variable. It's just an integer pointing at an arbitrary location in the RAM chips. It could point to absolutely anything. Don't use `id` when you want the compiler to warn you of mistakes like the one you made here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your first example to:

```
id appdel = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] class];
```

And then it will be the same as the second example.

Answer (score 1):

Those two arguments are not the same.

```
id appdel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

is an *instance* of the MyAppDelegate class, and

```
id casualcore_app_delegate = objc_getClass("MyAppDelegate");
```

is the *class* itself.

Now the first argument of `class_copyPropertyList()` is a *class*, therefore it works
in the second example, but not in the first. If you change

```
objc_property_t * property_list = class_copyPropertyList(appdel, &property_count);
```

to

```
objc_property_t * property_list = class_copyPropertyList([appdel class], &property_count);
```

then your first example works as well, and gives the same result.